# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Here's what I'm trying to prove:

Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist.

---

Proof Attempt:

Suppose that the limit does exist and denote it by $L$. Then, let $\epsilon > 0$. So:

$$\exists \delta > 0: 0 < |x| < \delta \implies |\frac{1}{x} - L| < \epsilon$$

In particular, we note that:

$$\frac{1}{|x|} < |L| + \epsilon$$

So, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is bounded when $|x| > \frac{1}{|L| + \epsilon}$. Now, let $\delta = \frac{1}{|L|+\epsilon}$. So, we have:

$$0 < |x| < \delta = \frac{1}{|L|+\epsilon}$$

$$\frac{1}{|x|} > |L| + \epsilon$$

$$|f(x)| > |L| + \epsilon$$

In other words, $f(x)$ is not bounded in this deleted neighbourhood of $x = 0$. Previously, we proved that if $f(x)$ does have a limit, then it is bounded on some neighbourhood of $x = 0$. So, our result above gives us a contradiction.

Hence, $L$ does not exist. This proves the desired assertion.

Can someone check if my proof above works or not? If it doesn't, how could I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not OK.

You claim:

1. That if the limit exists, then $f(x)$ is bounded for $|x|>\frac{1}{|L|+\epsilon}$.
2. That $f$ is not bounded on a deleted neighborhood of $0$.

And then, from 1 and 2, conclude that $L$ does not exist. This is not OK. There is no clear logical connection between claims 1 and 2 and the conclusion. You should explain further why the conclusion follows.

---

Also, in general, your attempt starts of saying "supposing that the limit exists". This suggests to the reader you are doing a proof by contradiction, however, there is later no point where you clearly say that you have now reached a contradiction. To make your proof clear to people who read it, it would be a good idea to explicitly explain where exactly the contradiction occurs.

In other words, proofs by contradiction usually have the form of:

> Suppose $\neg A$ is true. ... ... ... Therefore, $B$ is true. However, we also know that $\neg B$ is true, which means we have reached a contradiction. We therefore conclude our initial assumption was false, and that $A$ must be true.

Comment: Ah, so i should have said the following: If the limit exists, f is bounded on a deleted neighbourhood of 0. That's something I've already proven. Since, f is not bounded on a deleted neighbourhood of 0, the limit cannot exist.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats Indeed. But you would need to prove, strictly, that $f$ is not bounded on a deleted neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Haven't I proven that in the last few lines of my argument? Like, I've shown that there is a choice of $\delta$ such that $f(x)$ is not bounded on that deleted neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats I don't see where exaclty this is proven. This may simply be because the proof is vaguely written, which goes back to my point: **be explicit** with what you claim, and what you have proven.

Comment: So, like, I picked $\delta = \frac{1}{|L|+\epsilon}$. So, $|x|<\delta \iff |f(x)| > |L|+\epsilon > \epsilon$. Surely that shows that $f(x)$ is not bounded for that deleted neighbourhood? If it doesn't, how do I show that $f(x)$ is unbounded there?

Comment: Ah, let me try to edit my proof and see if it works better.

Comment: Alright, so I've edited my proof to make my reasoning more explicit and clear. Since I'm just learning this stuff, it's fair that I'd have to do that. Is it better now or does it still require some improvement?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats You didn't prove that $f$ is unbounded. You only proved that it is bigger than $|L| + \epsilon$. That's not the same as unbounded. A function is unbounded if it has **no** bounds. You only proved that $|L|+\epsilon$ is not its bound. There are plenty of bounded functions which are bigger than $|L|+\epsilon$. For example, the function $f(x)=|L|+2\epsilon$ is a constant function, it is bounded, but bigger than $|L|+\epsilon$.

Comment: Uhhhh I'm not gonna lie, I have no idea how to fix the proof then. Like, I know that I have to show that it's unbounded. So, I suppose that $M \in \mathbb{R^+}$ is a bound. So, $|f(x)| \leq M$. That's only true if $\frac{1}{M} \leq |x|$. But if I pick $\delta = \frac{1}{M}$, then $|x| < \frac{1}{M}$ so $|f(x)| > M$. That would be a contradiction, no? I'm just playing around with things and hoping that something works lol

Comment: @AbhijeetVats Yes! You have just shown that for every $M$, there exists some $\delta$ such that $0<x<\delta\implies |f(x)| > M$. This is *exactly* the definition of $f$ being unbounded on a deleted neighborhood of $0$!

Comment: Oh nice, that was easy. Thank you!

Comment: @AbhijeetVats No, it wasn't easy. It is **simple**. That's not the same. It took you several tries to get it right, and that's OK - it's what learning is all about. The hard part isn't writing out the solution once you figure it out (because the solution is simple). The hard part was getting to the solution, and figuring out that it is indeed the solution.

Comment: Mmmh yea, I'll probably have to struggle a lot more to get it right more easily next time. In any case, thanks for your help :D

Comment: @AbhijeetVats It'll be slightly easier the next time. And then slighly easier again the next time. Just keep at it, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. I do hope it gets easier, assuming my brain doesn't keep failing me lol